# how to fix with array OutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm working on a project for school where we have to spin a cube a number of times and find the longest run of the numbers that are received from the cube. I am almost finished with the code, and it complies, but whenever I run it I get the same error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at number_cube.number_cube.cubeToss(number_cube.java:20)
    at number_cube.number_cube.main(number_cube.java:10)
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Here is my code:

```
public class number_cube { 
    public static int ans;
    public static void main(String[]args){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many times would you like to toss the cube?");
        ans = scan.nextInt();
        cubeToss();
        getLongestRun();
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static int arr[] = new int[ans];

    public static int[] cubeToss(){
        for(int i = 0; i < ans; i++){
            int randnum = (int) (1 + Math.random() * (6-1));
            arr[i] = randnum;
        }
        return arr;
    }

    public static void getLongestRun(){
        int longest = 0;
        int length = 1;
        for(int i = 1; i < ans; i++)
            if(arr[i] == arr[i-1]){
                length++;
            } 

            else{
                length = 1;
            }

        if(length > longest){
            longest = length;
        }

        System.out.println("The longest run is " + longest + ".");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You used the variable `ans` as the length of your `arr` array, but when the array was created, `ans` didn't have a value (Java initialized it to 0), so the `arr` array has length 0.  The `main` method isn't called until the class is initialized; all `static` variables are initialized before the `main` method is called.

Don't create the array until you have a valid length:

```
ans = scan.nextInt();
arr = new int[ans];  // Add this line.
cubeToss();
```

Comment: It's increible how many upvotes a person with many points can get in no time. I think OP thought the call `public static int arr[] = new int[ans];` workes as intended, because it is placed under the main method. You may want to add how variable initialization works in Java, now that you solved 90% of the puzzle already. :)

Comment: Chapter [12 Execution](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html) in the JLS is some nice not so light reading that may be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You need to initialize the array after you got the value `for` ans. Currently you are initialize the Array with `ans = 0` at the startup for the program (where `ans` is 0).

A correct solution may be:

```
 public static void main(String[]args){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many times would you like to toss the cube?");
        arr[] = new int[scan.nextInt()];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int arr[] = new int[ans];
```

From the [**jls-12.4:**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4)  when The JVM is still trying to execute the method `main` of class `number_cube`, the invocation is permitted only if the class has been initialized. However, Initialization of a class consists of executing its static *initializers* and the *initializers* for `static` fields (class variables) declared in the class.

That is why, static fields declared in class context always gets instantiated first. 
For  your class which are: `int[] arr` and `int ans`. `static` variable `ans` initialized to the value `0` which is default value of integer. Hence, Instantiating the `static` array `arr` has the length `0` and being empty. When you are trying to access it in the `cubeToss()` function using a loop, an `AIBE 0` is being thrown as the array has length `0`(or, the array is empty).

So, after reading the `ans` in the main method in the `main` method using `ans = scan.nextInt();`, try creating the array in the main method: `arr = new int[ans]`

Answer (score 0):

`public static int[] arr;`

and then initialize only after getting `ans` from `System.in`